# Expected [!]interface|@interface|class|enum

Tags: android, proguard

Unable to generate sign APK because of proguard.

I am using enum, interfaces in project.

please help.

Comment: I face the same issue

Comment: Hello @Faheem, did you able to find any solution yet? I am facing the same issue. Need help

Answer (score 5):

maybe you write like this

```
-keep com.example.myapplication.bean.**{*;}
```

correct

```
-keep class com.example.myapplication.bean.**{*;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  you missed class keyword in proguard file-keep class

```
> com.all.effect.photo.editor.models.applist{*;}
```

you need to write class keyword